# How to find continuous sub-array whose sum is equal to a particular number in O(n) time complexity

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have solved the same question but the time complexity of my code is O(n^2). Here is my code where I run two loops because of which my time complexity becomes O(n^2). Is there any way I can alter my code so as to solve the same problem in O(n) time?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PracticeOne {

public static void checkSum(int[] arr, int N) {
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum = 0;
        for(int j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
            sum += arr[j];
            if(sum == N) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, i, j+1)));
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[] arr = {5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 5, 5};
    int N = 10;

    checkSum(arr, N);
}

}
```

Comment: Are the numbers always >= 0?

Comment: @Stephen C Correct counterquestion. If they are, then the riddle is easy :)

Comment: @Stephen C The problem doesn't talk about whether the numbers are positive or negative. But I've solved it presuming the fact that there are only positive numbers in the array.

Comment: Assumptions should be stated in your Question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically want 2 pointer-indexes, start and end. Move beginning index if sum is too high and move end index is sum is too low.

I haven't tested it much but here is the basic idea:

```
public static void checkSum(int[] arr, int N) { // O(n)
int sum = 0;
int startPoint = 0;
for(int endPoint = 0; endPoint < arr.length; endPoint++) {
    sum += arr[endPoint];
    while(sum > N) {
        sum -= arr[startPoint++];
    }
    if(sum == N) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, startPoint, endPoint+1)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can alter my code so as to solve the same problem in O(n) time?

Yes, but only, if you are guaranteed, that all values in the array are positive or 0. You iterate over your array, and check the sum each time (after adding the next element). If you are above N, you drop the oldest value, until you are equal or below N again. This you repeat, until you hit N or the end of the array:

```java
public static void checkSum(int[] arr, int N) {
    if (N == 0) {
        System.out.println("[]");
    }
    int sum = 0;

    LinkedList<Integer> elements = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int value : arr) {
        sum += value;
        elements.addLast(value);
        while (sum > N && !elements.isEmpty()) {
            Integer oldest = elements.pollFirst();
            sum -= oldest;
        }
        if (sum == N) {
            System.out.println(elements);
        }
    }
}
```

This will only visit each number twice, at most, because you will only add it once, and remove it once.

Result:

```
[5, 4, 1]
[4, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 1]
[1, 4, 5]
[5, 5]
```